# How to search for "X Y" words in Google Web Search while exculding pages that have X and no Y after it

Tags: google-search, search

I want to use Google Web Search to do a web search like this:
Find pages that contain the phrase "red car" while excluding the pages that have the word "red" and no "car" after it. If we just entered "red car" there will be pages that contain that combination while also containing something like "red sun" just for example, and I don't want that.

P.S: The real search terms I want to enter are in Arabic, so I thought I had to put something in English here. The reason for this complex search is to determine the most widely used name of a certain book.

Comment: I thought that putting "quotes" around the "two words" would work, but Google is returning results that include "car red" as well as "red car". (I actually searched for "squid plastic", which is obviously less common than "red car". Google returned results containing "plastic squid".)